# Is there a specific term for meteorology on other planets?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm aware of the term "exometeorology", but that seems to connote meteorology on exoplanets outside our solar system. I'm wondering if there's a single word I can use to refer to meteorology on Venus or Mars, i.e.,

> The *Venera 12* missions returned a wealth of data that was useful to the terrestrial planet meteorology community.

dictionary.com doesn't have a definition for exometeorology, anyway.

Comment: Does the definition of meteorology exclude the atmospheric sciences on planets other than Earth?

Comment: Since meteorology is about weather patterns, it is not specific to earth. But the _study_ of weather patterns _is_ specific to earth as that is where all the meteorologists are who study it. If one wishes to refer to weather elsewhere than on earth, one must specify the location as it will, otherwise (quite properly) be assumed that earth is the focus. _Venusian and Martian meteorology_ would be my guess at the answer.

Comment: @NigelJ there are absolutely meteorologists who focus on other planets, in fact, they're hot fields of study at the moment. A cursory Google Scholar search for "Venus meteorology" yields about 23,600 papers. I'd imagine context matters. When talking about Mars, one needn't say "martian meteorologists" over and over, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single word, but **planetary meteorology** seems to fit the bill (as opposed to terrestrial meteorology). It requires some particular reading of the words though (ie, planetary to mean non-Earth planets, and terrestrial to mean Earth), but it has been done. See, for example, https://global.jaxa.jp/article/special/explore/imamura02_e.html

> Japan is one of the leading countries in the field of terrestrial meteorology. With that background, I believe that we can lead the research of **planetary meteorology** as well.

Another candidate is **extra-terrestrial meteorology**. See, for example, https://www.worldcat.org/title/horizon-the-weirdest-weather-in-the-universe/oclc/1089752078

> Now scientists have started looking to the heavens and wondering what the weather might be like on other planets. Today, we are witnessing the birth of **extra-terrestrial meteorology**, as technology is allowing astronomers to study the weather on other planets like never before.

Or https://www.scisnack.com/2017/10/17/meteorology-is-out-of-this-world-extra-terrestrial-meteorology/

> So just as investigating Earthly weather can tell us about processes occurring on other planets, delving into **extra-terrestrial meteorology** can shed some light on how our own atmosphere does, or does not behave.

Answer (score 0):

Meteorology is the process of examining phenomena and atmosphere patterns to predict the weather. The word is the same regardless of which planet you're talking about. For example, "The meteorology on Earth is different from the meteorology on Mars."